# Why do heli PC2 operations require highest obstacle clearance

Tags: helicopter, regulations, icao, australia, obstacle-clearance

In designing a helipad I notice that the Australian requirements (AC139.R-01) for obstacle clear gradients specify that the slope category (12.5% slope) generally applies to PC2 operations, whereas categories A (4.5% slope) and B (8% slope) are said to generally apply to PC1 and PC3 operations respectively:

> The slope design categories in Table 2 may not be restricted to a
> specific performance class of operations and may be applicable to more
> than one performance class of operation. The slope design categories
> depicted in Table 2 represent minimum design slope angles and not
> operational slopes. Slope category "A" generally corresponds with
> helicopters operated in performance class 1; slope category "B"
> generally corresponds with helicopters operated in performance class
> 3; and slope category "C" generally corresponds with helicopters
> operated in perfromance class 2. Consultation with helicopter
> operators will help to determine the appropriate slope category to
> apply according to the heliport environment and the most critical
> helicopter type for which the heliport is intended.

This is in contrast with ICAO's notes in Doc 9261, which explain category A as applying to PC1 operations with one engine inoperative, and Cat B and C applying to different scenarios where All Engines Operating (AEO) is assumed.

Is there a logical explanation as to why the Australian rules might consider categories B and C to  be applicable to PC3 and PC2 respectively? As a former CPL-H myself I just can't see the reasoning behind it.